# Is it possible to get data from a plot in R

Tags: r

I have this plot where I plotted patient ID's on the x axis and BMI on the y axis. I found a cluster of a data in "severely underweight" category as u can see in the plot. How can I get a table of all those points which are in here?

OR

How can I extract one category from a column in R. [image]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example. Since you presumably have the original data to create the plot, simplest would be to extract the data from the orginal data.frame.  If you really need to get data from the plot, you can use   `layer_data()` or `ggplot_build()`

Comment: `df[df$weight_level == "Severely underweight", ]`

Comment: Both methods worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

1. your data is the `d1` data frame
2. the category is given by the `group` column

Then one possibility is to use `dplyr` package:

```r
suw <- filter(d1,  group == "Severely underweight")
```